# Is Melvin Potter one of the bodies found by Poindexter in the freezer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-2015

In Season 3, Episode 13 of *Daredevil*, "A New Napkin", Agent Poindexter is directed to a freezer where Wilson Fisk has hidden several bodies of people he's killed. One is a bald man with a beard and goatee that, to me, has a passing resemblance to [Melvin Potter](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Melvin_Potter), last seen being arrested by the FBI (some agents of which have been suborned by Wilson Fisk) in Episode 7, "Aftermath". Was there any word from the show's producers as to whether that is supposed to be Melvin?

[image: Image of bearded bald man in freezer] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That is not Melvin Potter's body.**

Aside from the fact that it's not Potter's actor, Matt Gerald, it is my assumption that it is a member of the [**Cleaning Crew**](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Cleaning_Crew), the assassins hired by Felix Manning to kill Benjamin Poindexter's "love interest," Julie Barnes. They were most likely killed as to avoid their crimes being traced back to Kingpin.

Answer (score 0):

It's the FBI agent Fisk kills in his SUV when he gets the bad news about Nadeem being in the wind.

Comment: Can you name an episode this FBI agent appeared in, and provide an image of the character for comparative purposes?